# Javax mail sendpulse smtp server

Tags: java, email, smtp, jakarta-mail

I'm trying to setup Javax.mail to work with sendpulse smtp server (actually had different prob with other also).

currently it's always **just hangs here** `System.out.println("\n\n 3rd ===> Get Session and Send mail");`. No exceptions (even i setup a timeouts), nothing.

Also, debug shown me that `transport` contains login value as `mypcname@smtp-pulse.com`, which is not right. and the `defaultPort = 465` (instead of 2525 set by me in properties)

smtp serve configured by input string `smtp-pulse.com,2525,maemail@yahoo.com,mypass` ->

the **current method to send** (tried a lot of different options):

```
public SMTPresponce SendHtmlEmail(String receipient){
    Integer timeout = 20000;

    logger.info("Sending to: "+receipient);

    // Step1
    System.out.println("\n 1st ===> setup Mail Server Properties..");
    mailServerProperties = System.getProperties();
    mailServerProperties.setProperty("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
    mailServerProperties.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", accountSMTP.getHost());
    mailServerProperties.setProperty("mail.smtp.port", accountSMTP.getPort());
    mailServerProperties.setProperty("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    mailServerProperties.setProperty("mail.smtp.ssl.enable", "true");
    mailServerProperties.setProperty("mail.smtp.ssl.trust", "*");
    mailServerProperties.setProperty("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    mailServerProperties.setProperty("mail.smtp.timeout", timeout.toString());
    mailServerProperties.setProperty("mail.smtp.connectiontimeout", timeout.toString());


    try {
        System.out.println("\n\n 2nd ===> get Mail Session..");
        getMailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(mailServerProperties, new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
            @Override
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication(accountSMTP.getLogin(), accountSMTP.getPassword());
            }
        });
        generateMailMessage = new MimeMessage(getMailSession);
        generateMailMessage.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(receipient));
        generateMailMessage.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.CC, new InternetAddress("test@mail.com"));
        try {
            generateMailMessage.setFrom(new InternetAddress(messageMy.getFinalFrom(), messageMy.getReply_to()));
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        generateMailMessage.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(receipient));
        generateMailMessage.setSubject(messageMy.getFinalTopic());
        generateMailMessage.setContent(messageMy.getFinalBody(), "text/html; charset=utf-8");

        // Send message
        // Step3
        System.out.println("\n\n 3rd ===> Get Session and Send mail");
        Transport transport = getMailSession.getTransport("smtp");

        // Enter your correct gmail UserID and Password
        transport.sendMessage(generateMailMessage, generateMailMessage.getAllRecipients());
        transport.close();

        return SMTPresponce.SEND_SUCCESS;

    }
    catch (AuthenticationFailedException ex){
        return SMTPresponce.AUTH_FAIL;
    }
    catch (MessagingException mex) {
        logger.error(mex.getCause());
        mex.printStackTrace();
        if(mex.getCause().toString().contains("Connection timed out"))
            return SMTPresponce.TIMEOUT;
        return SMTPresponce.SEND_FAIL;
    }

}
```

Comment: Fix these [common JavaMail mistakes](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#commonmistakes).  If it still doesn't work, update your post with the new code and post the debug output.

Comment: i tried multiple options + asked someone else to try. (working as separate JAVA app)
The reason is most likely that i run it in Spring app (and have to run in Spring App) and the `Session.getDefaultInstance` or `Session.getInstance` are for some reason not catching the settings from `mailServerProperties`

Comment: If you read the links above, you'll understand why Session.getDefaultInstance might be ignoring your properties.  Again, if you've fixed all the mistakes and it's still not working, post the updated code and the JavaMail debug output.

Comment: Again, we made on work as standalone JAVA script and in Groovy.
particularly on my environment with Spring Boot it doesn't work. and it's also `Session.getInstance`

Comment: Debug output???

Comment: always the same - not throwing the error, nothing.
But yep i can see in debugger that `transport.sendMessage` doesn't catching the properties - it uses the default URL, port, login and password (only the smtp server's domain is right.).

Some conflict with spring environment i guess.. but not really tracable

Comment: I can't say without seeing the [JavaMail debug output](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#debug) and your updated code.